# Exporting from access database to XML

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

i have 2 textboxes created in a Form in microsoft Access, how can i export using VBA value of that textboxes  in an XML document using a button in a form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'*****************************************************************
'This is how the main structure of the XMl file is created in VBA
'Use this as guidance to create new XML files.
'*****************************************************************

Sub CreateXML()

Dim objDom As DOMDocument
Dim objRootElem As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objSubRootElem As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objMemberElem As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objSubMemberElem As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objMemberRel As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim objMemberName As IXMLDOMElement

Set objDom = New DOMDocument    

' Creates root element
'Set objRootElem = objDom.createElement("r1")
'objDom.appendChild objRootElem

' Creates sub root element
'Set objSubRootElem = objDom.createElement("r2")
'objRootElem.appendChild objSubRootElem

' Creates Error Date & Time element
'Set objMemberElem = objDom.createElement("r3")
'objSubRootElem.appendChild objMemberElem

' Create element under Member element, and
' gives value "some guy"
'Set objMemberName = objDom.createElement("r3_Tag")
'objMemberElem.appendChild objMemberName
'objMemberName.Text = "value"

' Creates User Name element
'Set objMemberElem = objDom.createElement("r2_tag")
'objSubRootElem.appendChild objMemberElem
'objMemberElem.Text = "value"

' Creates Error Date & Time element
'Set objMemberElem = objDom.createElement("r3")
'objSubRootElem.appendChild objMemberElem

' Create element under Member element, and
' gives value "some guy"
'Set objMemberName = objDom.createElement("r3_Tag")
'objMemberElem.appendChild objMemberName
'objMemberName.Text = "value"

' Creates User Name element
'Set objMemberElem = objDom.createElement("r2_tag")
'objSubRootElem.appendChild objMemberElem
'objMemberElem.Text = "value"
```

' To make this some what more readable for humans, we need to add formatting, indent it and add a
carriage return before its children. Then recursively
format the children with increased indentation.

```
Sub FormatXmlNode(ByVal node As IXMLDOMNode, ByVal indent As Integer)
    Dim child As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim text_only As Boolean

    ' Do nothing if this is a text node.
    If TypeOf node Is IXMLDOMText Then Exit Sub

    ' See if this node contains only text.
    text_only = True
    If node.HasChildNodes Then
        For Each child In node.ChildNodes
            If Not (TypeOf child Is IXMLDOMText) Then
                text_only = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next child
    End If

    ' Process child nodes.
    If node.HasChildNodes Then

        ' Add a carriage return before the children.
        If Not text_only Then
            node.InsertBefore node.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(Chr(10)), node.FirstChild
        End If

        ' Format the children.
        For Each child In node.ChildNodes
            FormatXmlNode child, indent + 2
        Next child
    End If

    ' Format this element.
    If indent > 0 Then

        ' Indent before this element.
        node.ParentNode.InsertBefore node.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(Space$(indent)), node

        ' Indent after the last child node.
        If Not text_only Then node.appendChild node.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(Space$(indent))

        ' Add a carriage return after this node.
        If node.NextSibling Is Nothing Then
            node.ParentNode.appendChild node.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(Chr(10))
        Else
            node.ParentNode.InsertBefore node.OwnerDocument.createTextNode(Chr(10)), node.NextSibling
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

' Saves XML data to disk.

```
On Error Resume Next
MkDir ("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & _
"\Desktop\FXML_FILES") 'Creates folder on desktop, ignores error if it already exists
On Error GoTo 0

objDom.Save ("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & _
"\Desktop\XML_FILES\" & "filename.xml")
```